# Triggering alerts on Prometheus dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, devops, prometheus

Is it possible to trigger some alerts on the Prometheus dashboard by manually stopping respective services on the Kubernetes cluster in order to verify that I'm receiving alert for issues on Prometheus dashboard ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using tools such as [chaos toolkit](https://docs.chaostoolkit.org/drivers/kubernetes/) to do this declaratively and automatically instead of doing it manually. This is called chaos engineering more generally.

```
{
    "title": "Do we remain available in face of pod going down?",
    "description": "We expect Kubernetes to handle the situation gracefully when a pod goes down",
    "tags": ["kubernetes"],
    "steady-state-hypothesis": {
        "title": "Verifying service remains healthy",
        "probes": [
            {
                "name": "all-our-microservices-should-be-healthy",
                "type": "probe",
                "tolerance": true,
                "provider": {
                    "type": "python",
                    "module": "chaosk8s.probes",
                    "func": "microservice_available_and_healthy",
                    "arguments": {
                        "name": "myapp"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "method": [
        {
            "type": "action",
            "name": "terminate-db-pod",
            "provider": {
                "type": "python",
                "module": "chaosk8s.pod.actions",
                "func": "terminate_pods",
                "arguments": {
                    "label_selector": "app=my-app",
                    "name_pattern": "my-app-[0-9]$",
                    "rand": true
                }
            },
            "pauses": {
                "after": 5
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Great, it helps. But its having less number of scenarios to test on. is there anything similar to test calico, persistent volumes related issues as well?

Comment: I am not sure..you need to explore..there are couple of other chaos tools as well as some commercial products

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gremlin to achieve this goal too. First, install the Gremlin agent on your Kubernetes cluster using the helm chart: https://github.com/gremlin/helm/

Next, shutdown the specific services using the Kubernetes features within Gremlin. You can control the blast radius by selecting 1 pod/1 service or many pods/services. This is a tutorial that I wrote on this topic: https://www.gremlin.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-gremlin-with-kubernetes/.

Validating monitoring and alerting is a great use case for Chaos Engineering. As you said, triggering alerts on the Prometheus dashboard by manually stopping respective services on the Kubernetes cluster. This will enable you to verify alerts for issues on your Prometheus dashboard. This tutorial explains how to use Gremlin webhooks with Grafana and Prometheus: https://www.gremlin.com/community/tutorials/visualize-chaos-experiments-in-grafana-with-gremlin-webhooks/